vanilla javascript :: throw new Error inside async function is not executing
I want to terminate the script and literally throw new Error
when the web server cannot find the resource file (404).
the console confirm that the response.status indeed is 404
but I am not getting the error and the script keep on running
async function readFile() {
  let hash = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 7);

  const [dbResponse, yearResponse] = await Promise.all([
    fetch("db?" + hash).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 404) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
      }
    }),
    fetch(cYear + "?" + hash).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      if (response.status === 404) {
        throw new Error(response.status);
      }
    }),
  ]);

  const db = await dbResponse.text();
  const yDb = await yearResponse.text();

  return [db, yDb];
}


how are you calling readFile() - perhaps that's where you're doing something wrong? Also, are there any errors on the browser developer tools console?

You're throwing the errors inside those .then() callbacks. Also you're not returning anything from those. Really, it's best to avoid mixing .then() chains and async + await style code.

@Pointy it should work as intended

If you reject one of your promises, that doesn't mean that the other pending fetch request will suddenly abort. These non-JS asynchronous tasks will do their thing and eventually, when a response from these requests comes in, the corresponding promise will resolve, and attached then callbacks will still be called.

"I am not getting the error": do you catch it on the promise that readFile returns?
